# How to configure Nexus Repository Manager to support npm audit

Tags: npm, nexus, audit, npm-audit

When I try to execute `npm audit` in my (Angular 7) app, I get the following npm error:

> npm ERR! code ENOAUDIT
>   npm ERR! audit Your configured registry
>   (https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/yyy/) does not
>   support audit requests, or the audit endpoint is temporarily
>   unavailable.

Does anyone know how I can get Nexus to support `npm audit`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As noted in the linked JIRA ([NEXUS-16954](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-16954)), it should be possible to workaround NXRM by using `npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org`.

UPDATE (May 11th 2020): As of NXRM version 3.23, npm audit should work with systems that have Sonatype Firewall or IQ server configured.  The message returned should no longer error but explain this.  A [further JIRA ticket](https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-23658) has been opened to track desire for this command to work without the workaround stated here but not implemented as of this update.

Answer (score 5):

The solution with `npm audit --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org` only works if your npm client has internet access to [`registry.npmjs.org`](https://registry.npmjs.org).

If this is not the case and you don't want to pay for Nexus Firewall or Nexus Lifecycle, you can set up another proxy that redirects all calls to https://nexus.xxx.com/repository/yyy/-/npm/v1/security/audits and all of its subpaths to https://registry.npmjs.org/-/npm/v1/security/audits.

Something like https://github.com/chovyy/npm-audit-proxy might be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Oh, it seems, I cannot:

https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-16954

> "We are currently investigating the best way to implement NPM Audit and it is a priority for us, watch this space." (as of July 2019)